# What is equivalent query as SQL LIKE clause with Prefix and suffix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch

I want to search from *Elastic Search* with search box text value having **Prefix** and **Suffix** in `.net` `C#` using `NEST`. Suppose I search `"apple"` it give me output only `"apple"` and I want output like `"apple"`, `"apple mobile"`, `"apple earphone"`, `"apple iPhone 7"` etc.

Also if I search `"ppl"` then also I want output like `"apple"`, `"apple mobile"`, `"apple earphone"`, `"apple iPhone 7"` etc.

Comment: You can use `*` as wildcard. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Comment: Wildcard would probably get what you want, but seams to me you should look into setting up mappings as well since "SQL LIKE" is not how you should think about searches in elastic search.